# FormBuilder not apply changes on cells

Tags: javascript, html, json, datagrid, form.io

I'm building a form with `form.builder` from a predefined list of components. What I'm trying to do is, after making a GET request that returns data, fill the columns of the form with the values ​​of the request.

This is my code:
The function where I fill `dataGrid` component

```
function fillDataGridWithResponseData(configurationComponents, data) {
    const dataGridComponent = configurationComponents.components.find(component => component.key === 'dataGrid');

console.log('data' + JSON.stringify(data))

if (dataGridComponent) {
    const dataGridRows = dataGridComponent.components || [];

    const responseRows = data.dataGrid[0];

    for (const key in responseRows) {
        if (responseRows.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            const columnComponent = dataGridRows.find(component => component.key === key);
            console.log('key: ' + JSON.stringify(key))

            if (columnComponent) {
                columnComponent.value = responseRows[key];
                columnComponent.label = responseRows[key];

                console.log('responseRows[key]: ' + JSON.stringify(responseRows[key]))
                console.log('columnComponent: ' + JSON.stringify(columnComponent))
                console.log('columnComponent.defaultValue : ' + JSON.stringify(columnComponent.defaultValue))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

This is where I invoke that, in window.onload()

```
 axios.get(`${baseURL}/${baseUserURL}/${idUser}`)
            .then(function (response) {
                const data = response.data.data;
                console.log('data: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
                Formio.builder(document.getElementById('builder'), configurationComponents)
                    .then(function (form) {
                        fillDataGridWithResponseData(configuracionComponentes, data);
                        form.render();

                })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log('Error', error);
            });
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log('', error);
        });
```

The format of JSON Response is similar that:
'data.dataGrid[]'

I don't understand why the values ​​in the datagrid cells are not displayed. The render function is supposed to reload the form